# Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, httpd, service

```
* httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-06-08 20:42:00 CEST; 7min ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 12757 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 27094 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -k graceful (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 12755 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 12755 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 08 20:42:00 vz38050 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jun 08 20:42:00 vz38050 systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 08 20:42:00 vz38050 kill[12757]: kill: cannot find process ""
Jun 08 20:42:00 vz38050 systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 08 20:42:00 vz38050 systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Jun 08 20:42:00 vz38050 systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Jun 08 20:42:00 vz38050 systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

That's all that shows as a result of 'systemctl status httpd.service -l'. Journal looks pretty much the same. How can I debug this further?

Comment: Please post contents of apache error log. /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: @mzhaase Thanks, totally forgot to check this!
[Thu Jun 08 20:42:00.425100 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 12755] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /etc/httpd/logs/ssl_error_log for more information

I updated the certificate recently and forgot to update the path in ssl.conf. Please post an answer if you wish, I will mark it as correct.